# Capturing Linked data when rolling forward a word and excel file

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have two documents, a word and an excel that both get rolled forward on a monthly basis. So I would save down the word as "Sep 16 Word doc" and the excel as "Sep 16 Excel doc" and copy them to my October files, replacing the names so that there are now documents labelled "Oct 16 Word doc" and "Oct 16 Excel doc."

The word document uses data from the excel document in both tabular format as well as the body of the text.

Whilst I know how to link data from an excel to a word, I don't know how to make this persist during the rollforward without manually relinking everything from excel to word.

I'm certain that an easy way of doing this exists, but my knowledge of VBA isn't up to the task.